# CakePHP 2.0: Class 'String' not found at the end of my Model?

Tags: string, model, cakephp-2.0, classnotfound

Im using CakePHP 2.0

I have a Model for my Users which is very simple:

```
<?php
    App::uses('Model', 'Model');

    class User extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'User';
        public $validate = array(
            'username' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                    'message' => 'A username is required'
                )
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                    'message' => 'A password is required'
                )
            )
        );

        public function beforeSave(array $options = array()) {
            if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

However I keep getting the following error:

**Fatal Error: Class 'String' not found in /home/xxx/app/Model/User.php on line 27.**

The error disappears if I comment the beforeSave function.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
 public function beforeSave(array $options = array()) {
```

to

```
 public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
```